# How to convert .htaccess to a nginx equivalent?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, winginx

## How to convert .htaccess configuration to nginx?

## My .htacess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mvc/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]﻿
```

## I tried this:

## nginx configuration

```
location /mvc/public/ {
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^/mvc/public/(.+)$ /mvc/public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]﻿;
}
}
```

But this did not work!
Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[QSA,L]﻿` is not `nginx` syntax - see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

```
location /mvc/public/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/mvc/public/(.+)$ /mvc/public/index.php?url=$1 last﻿;
    }
}
```

Similar behaviour can be accomplished with `try_files` rather than the `if`:

```
location /mvc/public/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/mvc/public/(.+)$ /mvc/public/index.php?url=$1 last﻿;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.